# How can I change the current file to another in Windows Media Player?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using Visual Studio .Net Framework to create a slideshow that operates on its own after clicking the "play" button. My current issue is that I do not know how to go about making the application go to the next file in the document after the video has ended. At the moment I have it setup for the user to select a time period for how long they want each image displayed, but I would rather have this feature automated.
This is my current code :

```
{
    public partial class TVDisplay : Form
    {
       // Time f3 = new Time();
        public TVDisplay()
        {
            //f3.Show();         
            InitializeComponent();
            //both listview and listbox clear at initilize//
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            //xml file from first application is read for department information, and that path and department are placed in textbox3 to be read by the listbox//
            var xd = new XmlDocument();
            string pathz = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string filepath = pathz + @"\Assigned_Television.xml";
            xd.Load(filepath);
           // var list = xd.GetElementsByTagName("Television");
            textBox3.Text = xd.GetElementsByTagName("Path")[0].InnerText;
        }
        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {   
            //when esacpe is pressed, the display screen is windowed instead of fullscreen//
            if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
        //Page load//
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.stretchToFit = true;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";         //disables the play, pause, etc. buttons at the bottom of the windows media player//  
            listView1.Items.Clear();    //clears listview items//
            Repopulate();   //calls repopulate function//
            refreshtimer.Interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;
            //timer for when images need to be displayed//
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            int result = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);           
            tmr.Interval = result * 60 * 1001; 
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            tmr.Start();        
        }
        private void Repopulate()
        {
            foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox3.Text))
            {
                var dirName = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;
                listView1.Items.Add(dirName);
            }
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.Text);
            }
        }
        //hidden button that acts as a "play" button, taking url from textbox 1, playing the video, and looping it until it is time for the next image//
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(textBox4.Text);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = textBox4.Text; 
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);
        
        }
        
        // timer that clicks button one//
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            button1.PerformClick();    
        }

        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {        
        }
        //when the tvdisplay is shown, start button is clicked and button 1 (play button) is clicked//
        private void TVDisplay_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.PerformClick();
            button1.PerformClick();          
        }
        //hidden behind windows media player//
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            int result = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            tmr.Interval = result * 60 * 1000;
            //int result = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);           
           // tmr.Interval = 1 * 60 * 1000;
            //tmr.Interval = 180000;
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
            tmr.Start();
            //textBox2.Clear();
            var path = textBox3.Text;
            textBox4.Text = path + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void refreshtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            int x = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            Repopulate();
            //selects the first index once files are repopulated//
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = x;
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        }
        //hidden behind windows media display//
        private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.Enabled = false;
            timer3.Interval = 10000; //time in milliseconds
            timer3.Tick += timer3_Tick;
            timer3.Start();
            //startbutton.Enabled = false;
            if(listBox1.Items != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no content entered for display.", "Error");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else { 
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count; 
            }
           
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.PerformClick();
        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.Enabled = true;
            timer3.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Image/Video is displayed by Windows Media Player.

Comment: Instead of "visual studio" (which is just the development environment) you should rather tag the UI technology (e.g. winforms)

Comment: What is the type (fully qualified) of `axWindowsMediaPlayer1`?